# Categorizing a number based on ranges

Tags: ruby

I have some ranges defined:

```rb
very_low = <10
low = 11-20
medium = 21-30
high = 31-40
very_high = 41+
```

What is the most succinct way in Ruby to find out which category any given number is in?

e.g know that 23 would be 'medium'

Comment: Do you think you can provide more context?

Comment: The definition seems incomplete. Is that a hash with category names as keys and ranges as values?

Comment: It's whatever the best structure is.  That's up for deciding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
RANGES = {
  very_low:    (..10),
  low:       (11..20),
  medium:    (21..30),
  high:      (31..40),
  very_high: (41..)
}

def range_for(number)
  RANGES.find { |_, range| range.cover?(number) }.first
end

range_for(23)
#=> :medium
```

It uses [`Enumerable#find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) with [`Range#cover?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) to pick the matching range definition. The `find` method returns an array including both, key and value. The chained `first` call then picks the key from the array which will be the requested range identifier.

Answer (score 2):

you've changed your question, but you now have overlaps (40, and 40+) ... I don't know if you're working with integers or decimals, but I'm assuming integers because you're not dealing with "10" or "10.5" ... how about this:

```
def which_range? num
  ranges={
    very_low: (..10),
    low: (11..20),
    medium: (21..30),
    high: (31..40),
    very_high: (41..)
  }
  ranges.each do |key,val|
    return key if val.include?(num)
  end
  return false
end
```

example output:

```
2.7.2 :073 > which_range? 23
 => :medium
2.7.2 :074 > which_range? 7
 => :very_low
2.7.2 :075 > which_range? 25
 => :medium
2.7.2 :076 > which_range? 35
 => :high
2.7.2 :077 > which_range? 45
 => :very_high
2.7.2 :123 > which_range? 102
 => :very_high
2.7.2 :124 > which_range? -12
 => :very_low
```

Comment: You might want to move `ranges` out of the method and into a constant to avoid redefining the whole hash on each call.

Comment: I agree, especially if you want to reference `ranges` in another function, or interrogate what the range covers.  Only didn't because I was hashing something up quickly

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question correctly, then, perhaps, [case statement](https://www.rubyguides.com/2015/10/ruby-case/) is something you looking for

```rb
case some_number
when ..10 then 'very_low'
when 11..20 then 'low'
when 40.. then 'very_high'
...
end

# P.S.: for older versions without endless ranges:

case some_number
when -Float::INFINITY..10 then 'very_low'
when 11..20 then 'low'
when 40..Float::INFINITY then 'very_high'
...
end
```

Comment: In newer Ruby versions you also have open ranges like `..10` and `40..`

Comment: @Stefan for sure, I just saw that question was changed with such checks, before there was just ranges :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the ranges are consecutive, you could define the upper or lower bounds in an array in order from low to high (when using upper bounds) or from high to low (when using lower bounds). Then have an array with their respective name at the same index.

```rb
def range_name(number)
  range_names  = ['very_low', 'low', 'medium', 'high',   'very_high'  ]
  upper_bounds = [    10    ,   20 ,    30   ,   40  , Float::INFINITY] # inclusive

  index = upper_bounds.find_index { |upper_bound| number <= upper_bound }

  range_names[index]
end
```